# How to improve the appearance of sums under root in the denominator?

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-spacing

How to add space between sums and root in the denominator and between the fractional line and root?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
r = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n(y_i - \overline{y})^2}},
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Elena Greg, in short @egreg. ;-)

Comment: Which one of my answers was more appropriate for your needs?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I search for \displaystyle, but finally, I used both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `\displaystyle` both in the numerator and the denominator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
r = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n(y_i - \overline{y})^2}},
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Or you can put a `\strut` within each square root:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
r = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})}{\sqrt{\strut\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})^2} \sqrt{\strut\sum_{i = 1}^n(y_i - \overline{y})^2}},
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```